# How to modify the output of wp_terms_checklist when used within the built-in category metabox on edit posts?

Tags: categories, post-meta, taxonomy, metabox, walker

On the Edit Screen in the WP Admin there is a meta box for WP's built-in Category taxonomy. This meta box is built using `post_categories_meta_box()` (`/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`).

This meta box uses `wp_popular_terms_checklist( $tax_name )` and `wp_terms_checklist( $tax_name )` to output the actual categories (with checkboxes) within the meta box.

`wp_terms_checklist()` (`wp-admin/includes/template.php`) uses the `Walker_Category_Checklist` (`/wp-admin/includes/class-walker-category.checklist`) to build the categories/checkboxes.

`Walker_Category_Checklist` inherits from  `Walker` (`wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php`) just like a number of other WP walkers (`Walker_Nav_Menu`, `Walker_Comment`, `Walker_Category`, etc.).

When extending the `Walker_Nav_Menu` we can hook into the `wp_edit_nav_menu_walker` filter and return our custom walker. Is there a way to do this with `Walker_Category_Checklist`?

===

**Update 1:**

I see in `wp_terms_checklist()` there is:

`apply_filters( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', $args, $post_id );`

I'm thinking that I can hook into this filter, change the `walker` argument to a custom walker and that this may do the trick?

Comment: So did my answer answer your question, or do you need further explanation, assistance or something else?

Comment: Your answer was what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as the [documentation for `wp_terms_checklist()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_terms_checklist/#parameters) stated, you can use the `walker` argument (which is part of the `$args` parameter for the [`wp_terms_checklist_args` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_terms_checklist_args/)) to use a custom walker which modifies the output of the Category checklist generated by `wp_terms_checklist()`, e.g. the one in the "Categories" meta box on `wp-admin/post.php`.

Example where the custom walker is in a folder named `includes`:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', 'my_wp_terms_checklist_args', 10, 2 );
function my_wp_terms_checklist_args( $args, $post_id ) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/class-my-walker-category-checklist.php';

    $args['walker'] = new My_Walker_Category_Checklist;

    return $args;
}
```