# Modify Term List in Custom Taxonomy Meta Box

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, term-meta

For the life of me, I can't find the hook for altering the list of terms in a custom taxonomy metabox.

On the post-edit screen, instead of list of custom taxonomy terms like this...

```
[ ] Bob Dylan

[ ] Bruce Springsteen
```

...I want this:

```
[ ] Bob Dylan (link)

[ ] Bruce Springsteen (link)
```

...where "link" is a link to that term's page.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean in the block editor? or in the old classic editor?

Comment: Classic editor, thanks!

Comment: ah in that case it may be helpful to know that it's not a list but a tree, which means there's a walker class being used to display that metabox. If you get that link in there though, there's no guarantee clicking it will do anything other than select/unselect the checkbox though.

Comment: The html for it looks pretty straightforward:

`<li><label class="selectit"><input value="" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[term][]"> Name</label></li>`

I just need to insert a link in there:

`<li><label class="selectit"><input value="" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[term][]"> Name</label><a target="_blank" href="/taxonomy/term/">(link)</a></li>`

As long as it's outside the <label>, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this, I finally found the answer in this previous post:

[How to modify the output of wp_terms_checklist when used within the built-in category metabox on edit posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/387307/how-to-modify-the-output-of-wp-terms-checklist-when-used-within-the-built-in-cat)

I wasn't finding it because it's the Walker class, not a hook.